# Combine the output of two functions in a single table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using [a toy database of movies](https://github.com/dominiquealpinski/sql) to learn SQL.

I am trying to combine the output of two functions into a single table. The first function selects an actors name and year of birth/death. The second selects all of the movies and roles that that actor has played. I need the function to insert the output of the first function into a table/view and append the output of the second function to that same table/view.

My effort is:

```
-- creating a table into which results from function can be stored
create table results (q12 text);

---- working actors function ----- 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION 
get_all_foo(_pattern text) 
RETURNS void
AS $$
    DECLARE
        r text;
        _result record;
        BEGIN
        -- FIRST FUNCTION: return actors name and year of birth/death
            select distinct concat(people.name, ' (', people.year_born, '-', people.year_died, ')') into r
                from people
                left join 
                plays
                on people.id = plays.person_id
                left join
                movies
                on plays.movie_id = movies.id
                where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%');
            
            for _result in
            -- SECOND FUNCTION: returns all films and roles
            select concat(movies.title, ' ', '(', movies.year_made, ')', ' as ', STRING_AGG(plays.character, ','))
                from people
                left join 
                plays
                on people.id = plays.person_id
                left join
                movies
                on plays.movie_id = movies.id
                where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%')
                group by movies.id
             loop
                return next *; 
             end loop;               
        
           insert into results values(r);
           insert into results values(_results);
            
        END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM get_all_foo('clint eastwood');
```

When I go to use the function above, I get an error message "database: RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning set". Could someone tell me where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return next` requires an out parameter to be defined, but as your function is defined to return nothing, you can't use it like that. You would need to run the INSERTs inside the loop

But for what you are trying to do, you don't need loops or even a separate table, you can define the function to return a result directly. And as you don't need any procedural code to do this, a SQL function will also be enough.

The two outer joins in the first query also seem useless as you don't use any columns of the joined tables

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo(_pattern text) 
  RETURNS table(info text)
AS $$
  select distinct concat(people.name, ' (', people.year_born, '-', people.year_died, ')') 
  from people
  where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%')
  
  union all 
  
  select concat(movies.title, ' ', '(', movies.year_made, ')', ' as ', STRING_AGG(plays.character, ','))
  from people
    left join plays on people.id = plays.person_id
    left join movies on plays.movie_id = movies.id
  where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%')
  group by movies.id;
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then you can use it in the way you intend to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM get_all_foo('clint eastwood');
```

---

If you really want to do it with a slow loop in PL/pgSQL, you can do something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_foo_slow(_pattern text) 
  RETURNS table (info text) --<< define the output structure
AS $$
DECLARE
  _result record;
BEGIN
  select distinct concat(people.name, ' (', people.year_born, '-', people.year_died, ')') 
    into info --<< store it into the "output column"
  from people
  where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%');

  return next; ---<< implicitly returns the value of "info"
              
  for _result in
    -- SECOND FUNCTION: returns all films and roles
    select concat(movies.title, ' ', '(', movies.year_made, ')', ' as ', STRING_AGG(plays.character, ',')) as title
    from people
      left join plays on people.id = plays.person_id
      left join movies on plays.movie_id = movies.id
      where people.name ilike('%' || _pattern || '%')
      group by movies.id
   loop
      info := _result.title; --<< store it into the "output column"
      return next; ---<< implicitly returns the value of "info"
   end loop;               
END
$$ 
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you. If the first query contains either no matching results or multiple matching results I'd like to return a message saying either  'No matching name' or 'Ambiguous name', respectively.

I wondered if I could use an if-statement inside the PL/pgSQL that's been suggested in the answer, perhaps just below the first query after begin:

  if (info.actor_name is null) then
   select 'No matching name' into info;
   return info;
   exit;
   ELSIF (distinct info.actor_name) > 1 then
   select 'Ambiguous name' into info;
   return info;
   exit;
   END IF;